# Android Studio text font and density

Tags: android

How to make text bold in the android studio and also how to change the font style.
I added the font style in font folder and when I use it through **android:fontfamily**
it becomes somewhat distorted.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you asking how to make the text in Android Studio's text editor larger or text in your app larger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bold:
android:textStyle="bold"

For the font: 
android:fontFamily="@font/yourfonthere"

For the blurryness I would try to scale the text size down a little bit

Answer (score 0):

To change your text Style and your font in android, you have to add those two lines in your xml file.

```
android:textStyle="bold"
android:fontFamily="serif"
```